# Why can Serde not be used for Libra's serialization and deserialization of cryptographic purposes?

Tags: rust, cryptography, serde

> In Libra, participants pass around messages or data structures that often times need to be signed by a prover and verified by one or more verifiers. Serialization in this context refers to the process of converting a message into a byte array. Many serialization approaches support loose standards such that two implementations can produce two different byte streams that would represent the same, identical message. While for many applications, non-deterministic serialization causes no issues, it does so for applications using serialization for cryptographic purposes. For example, given a signature and a message, a verifier may not unable to produce the same serialized byte array constructed by the prover when the prover signed the message resulting in a non-verifiable message. In other words, to ensure message verifiability when using non-deterministic serialization, participants must either retain the original serialized bytes or risk losing the ability to verify messages. This creates a burden requiring participants to maintain both a copy of the serialized bytes and the deserialized message often leading to confusion about safety and correctness. While there exist a handful of existing deterministic serialization formats, there is no obvious choice. To address this, we propose Libra Canonical Serialization that defines a deterministic means for translating a message into bytes.

That is [what the Libra project says](https://github.com/libra/libra/tree/6a89e827b95405066dc83eec97eca2cb75bc991d/common/canonical-serialization). What is the real deterministic serialization? If serde is not deterministic, how it can deserialize back after serialize the datastruct?

Comment: Serde is a serialization library, but not a specific conversion of data into bytes. Serde supports many data formats and serializers, some of which are deterministic. In fact it looks like more recent versions of Libra have abandoned the bespoke canonical-serialization library in favor of [one based on Serde](https://github.com/libra/libra/tree/master/common/lcs). So I think the premise of your question, that Serde cannot be used for cryptographic purposes in Libra, is incorrect.

Comment: example of non-deterministic serialization: `{"a":1,"b":2}` and `{"b":2,"a":1}` in JSON are equivalent and unambiguous but the serialized data is different.

Comment: @kmdreko That's an example of redundancy in a data format -- but if the serializer always produces the same one for equivalent inputs, it is still deterministic. It would be more accurate to say that `serde_json`'s `Serializer` is an example of a non-deterministic serializer because it does not do that.

Comment: @trentcl Right, its the process that makes it deterministic, not necessarily the format. The example was to show how non-deterministic output can still be successfully deserialized; OP seemed unsure.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` and `HashMap` can have items inserted into different slots depending on the exact order of inserts, updates, and deletes.  Serializers of these data structures operate in slot order, emitting a sequence of (key, value) pairs.  Since slot order is nondeterministic, the serialized bytes will be nondeterministic.

Comment: Serializers may operate in slot order, but they don't have to serialize the entries in the order received. It is perfectly possible to deterministically serialize a `HashMap`, [for instance, by ordering all the entries lexicographically](https://github.com/libra/libra/blob/7030075bdf09fdf76c36d242378736489828901d/common/lcs/src/ser.rs#L500). Determinism is a property of a serialization, not a data structure.

Comment: It's possible, yes, but they don't generally do that.  The performance time and space penalties involved would conflict with the typical performance  design goals of such serializers.